# J2EE spring security one time link for password reset

Tags: security, spring, passwords, reset

I'm using spring (3.0) security for login in my J2EE spring webapp. I need to generate a link that will be sent by email (to a user that request password reset) and can be used one time only to reset a password and set a new one by a page with form. How can I generate this kind of link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how do you store user credentials:

If you implement `UserDetails` and `CredentialsContainer` for your User Entity, then you can add some kind of reset password boolean field with some kind of unique id which will be send as part of URL, if user navigate to correct URL according to link and he has reset password boolean flag enabled, then show him form which updates password and disables reset password flag on submit.